# When I was started hadoop cluster but cluster did not start and an issue of lacement Group

Tags: python-3.x, hadoop

`InvalidPlacementGroup.Unknown`The Placement Group '30633_20150226' is unknown.e4dc06ca-8d9e-469a-aa3f-dcddc045a9b6

Answer (score 0):

check what hadoop daemons are runnning using the command **jps**

If you are not seeing all the required services then you have to restart the processes.

```
sudo service hadoop-master stop

sudo service hadoop-master start
```